# Selenium WebDriver by xpath: search by text in child elements

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium WebDriver. (Java, if that matters).

I need to find an element, searching, among other things, for text that is under a subordinate element. I currently do it by looping through a list of elements and comparing getText() with the value I want, but I suspect it would be better to let the browser do it through xpath.

For example, here is an element I want to find:

```
<span role="button" class="mblToolBarButton mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow" tabindex="0" id="dojox_mobile_ToolBarButton_3" dir="ltr" widgetid="dojox_mobile_ToolBarButton_3"><span class="mblToolBarButtonArrow mblToolBarButtonLeftArrow mblColorDefault mblColorDefault45"></span><span class="mblToolBarButtonBody mblColorDefault"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" class="mblToolBarButtonText"><tbody><tr><td class="mblToolBarButtonIcon"></td><td class="mblToolBarButtonLabel">Back</td></tr></tbody></table></span></span>
```

After searching online I tried the following selector:

```
//*[contains(@class,'mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow') and text()[contains(.,'Back')]]
```

But it did not work.

Ideally i would like to search by the entire text, not a substring, so that this element with the text "Back" would be found, but another similar element with the text "Backup" would not be found. I don't need to concatenate text in different child elements.

What selector should I write? Thanks!

Comment: You could just use `.` instead of `text()`:
    `//*[contains(@class,'mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow') and .[contains(.,'Back')]]`.
The `.` matches against the text content of the tree, including all descendants, but `text()` only checks the text content of any direct child nodes.

Could be further simplified if instead of substring you want an exact match for *Backup*, in which case you can drop the second `contains(…)`:
    `//*[contains(@class,'mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow') and normalize-space(.) = 'Back']`.

You need the `normalize-space(.)` if you want to ignore inter-element space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like below?

```
//\*[text()='Back']/ancestor::*[@class='mblToolBarButton mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow']
```

Comment: Took me some time to realize this will find the ancestor, not the child. Thanks, this will probably work! But sometimes I need to find such elements under a given element only, by calling that element's findElement() method. I can remove the // at the start but will the /ancestor:: traverse the DOM above the initial element, anyway?

Answer (score 4):

You can use such construction:

```
//*[contains(@class,'mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow') and .//*[text()='Back']]
```

to seach for a parent element, which contains child with specified text. In this way element with text 'Back' will be found, but element with 'Backup' won't be.

BTW: it's more polite to provide readable html fragment instead of long line. For example:

```
<span role="button" class="mblToolBarButton mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow" tabindex="0" id="dojox_mobile_ToolBarButton_3" dir="ltr" widgetid="dojox_mobile_ToolBarButton_3">
    <span class="mblToolBarButtonArrow mblToolBarButtonLeftArrow mblColorDefault mblColorDefault45"></span>
    <span class="mblToolBarButtonBody mblColorDefault">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" class="mblToolBarButtonText">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="mblToolBarButtonIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mblToolBarButtonLabel">Back</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will make sure to use an auto-formatter next time I quote long HTML.

Comment: I went with this one, it works. In fact, I need to catch the element in case the text is directly under it, too, so here is the form I used, based on this one: `//*[contains(@class,'mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow') and (text()='Back' or .//*[text()='Back'])]`